# Blazor API default controllers route maping

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, blazor

How to force Blazor Web API so it to map as it was in some previous .NET Framework?

If I have this `UserController`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public UserController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [Route("GetUserName")]
    public String GetUserName()
    {
        return  httpContextAccessor!.HttpContext!.User?.Identity?.Name?;        
    }
}
```

Then what should I do to be able to delete
`[Route("api/[controller]")]` and `[Route("GetUserName")]`

and still be able to use same route? `.../user/getusername`
i want to be able to add new controllers / methods without having to specyfy any [Route("xxx")]. want it wo towk using default controller / action name for each own

I thought that

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
     });
```

will do it - but it is not... It does not change anything in that case...

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What is the problem? What the error you got? What are trying to reach?

Comment: i want to be able to add new controllers / methods without having to specyfy any [Route("xxx")]. want it wo towk using default controller / action name for each own

Comment: Good luck. You are not the first who waisted a lot of time trying the same, but without any success

Comment: so it was by default in .net framework couple years ago and now it is impossible ?? i do not belive :D it must be a way ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I see, you need to add MVC middleware service then, see below

```cs
builder.Services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    opt.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
});
...
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Full example

Controller

```cs
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public UserController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public String? GetUserName()
    {
        return httpContextAccessor!.HttpContext!.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

builder.Services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    opt.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}


app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Comment: hi thanks but no - this maps this controllers route attributes. itt is the same as 'app.MapControllers().'. i want to be able to use this controller/action route without any route attribute on controller/action (only if i want different then default route for controoelr/action then i would have to specyfi it in attribute.)

Comment: Updated my anwer, worked on a new .Net6 Blazor project with the above class to test it with.

Comment: thanks i was thinking about mvc but was not shure if it is right patch and if i even need this... still it is cimplaining Action methods on controllers annotated with ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute routed. but i see it is 'new way' od .netcore that does not support this thinkg by default